# Add UIView as subView on UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiactionsheet

I am working on project where I want to show UIActionsheet with three buttons Change,Cancel and Done and at the place of title I want to put UIView which has some labels. I have created dynamic UIView and I added it to actionsheet but its hiding behind buttons I tried it by all possible ways to setFrame,bounds but I am not able to find solution. I want to place this UIView at the top of UIActionsheet followed by buttons. If you have any doubts feel free to post comments.

**Here is My Code:**

```
-(IBAction)tapbutton:(id)sender
{
Lablesubview *view = [[Lablesubview alloc]init];
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                 destructiveButtonTitle:@"Change" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Done",nil];

   [actionSheet addSubview:view];
   [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this method, it will move all the buttons down by 100 pixels, please note that this type of modificaiton may result in your application rejection

```
-(IBAction)tapbutton:(id)sender
{   
    //create the view
    Lablesubview *view = [[Lablesubview alloc]init];
    //Set the frame
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 100);
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                             delegate:self 
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:@"Change" 
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Done",nil];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

    CGRect rect;

    //expand the action sheet
    rect = actionSheet.frame;
    rect.size.height +=100;
    rect.origin.y -= 100;
    actionSheet.frame = rect;

    //Displace all buttons
    for (UIView *vButton in actionSheet.subviews) {
        rect = vButton.frame;
        rect.origin.y += 100;
        vButton.frame = rect;
    }    


    //Add the new view
    [actionSheet addSubview:view];
}
```

Comment: It works great thanks. I just wanted to show five labels above buttons for that purpose I choose this solution but if you are saying that it may result in application rejection then what could be the way to achieve this where it won't turn into rejection.

Comment: Create your own view add your own labels and buttons, and then present it on screen [self.view addSubView:yourView];

Comment: Actually I already did it what you said in above comment. anyway it got confirmed from you. Thanks for valuable guidance.