# Replace button in UIActionSheet with UIView

Tags: ios, button, uiactionsheet

I want to replace one of the buttons in my `UIActionSheet` with a `UIView`. I am integrating Facebook into my app, and the log in button (FBLoginView) is a subclass of `UIView`. I want use this view as a button in a `UIActionSheet`. Is this possible?

**Edit:** I am trying to integrate facebook sharing in my app. For that, i hacve to use their sdk. For logging into facebook, they provide their own custom made view called 'FBLoginView' which has been made as a subclass of UIView. I just have to allocate memory and add this view to my own view. Then clicking on the view will call all functions provided in the sdk, open the fb app or safari and ask for login and password etc. and then come back to the app.

Now I want to put this button in a UIActionSheet. In the sheet I don't see an option for customizing its buttons. Even if there was an option, how can I use the UIView to create UIButton?

Comment: can you please explain more???

Answer (score 0):

I found this one from another user on StackOverflow, you might find it useful, as I did

[Add UIView as subView on UIActionSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051512/add-uiview-as-subview-on-uiactionsheet)

Good luck and let us know if you find any other solutions :)

UPDATE: I'd stay away from UIACtionSheet, as it's deprecated in iOS 8 onward. You need to use UIAlertController now. I'd use something like this:

```
UIAlertController * alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Connection Method"
                                                              message:@"Select Connection Method"
                                                       preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
//These will essentially be the buttons that we used to create for UIActionSheet. They are created pretty much the same way as how they used to,
//but you have to declare their corresponding action here too.

UIAlertAction* firstAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Title1"
                                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                        declaredVariable = NO;
                                                        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
                                                        [self doSomethingHereOrExecuteTheFunctionYouNeed];
                                                    }];
UIAlertAction* secondAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Title2 and so on"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                         BOOL newVarable = YES;
                                                         [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
                                                         [self followAlertControllerChoice];
                                                     }];

UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel button"
                                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                   [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                               }];
//Add buttons ("Actions") here
[alert addAction:firstAction];
[alert addAction:secondAction];
[alert addAction:cancel];

//Finally, present your alertcontroller
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

AFAIK, you can only add textfields to the alertcontroller, and you can do it like this:

```
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter your text here";
    textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
```

//So On so forth
    }];

Apparently, Apple doesn't want us to subclass the UIAlertController, per [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/):

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to mess around with `UIActionSheet`.

From [UIActionSheet Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> #### Subclassing Notes
>
> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:.

There are a quite a few action sheet replacements. Look at https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=uiactionsheet for a starting list.

My suggestion is to find one with the features you like instead of hacking `UIActionSheet`.