# UIPickerview not appearing at correct postion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

Sorry for asking such a stupid question but I dont know why my UIPickerView with done button is not appearing at the correct place. I am using the following code but I dont know why I am getting such issue.

```
actionSheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];


UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,40)];

[pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonTapped:)];
[barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonTapped:)];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];

[pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
[actionSheet addSubview:pickerToolbar];


//-----------
maritalStatusPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 216)];
maritalStatusPickerView.delegate = self;
maritalStatusPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;


[actionSheet addSubview:maritalStatusPickerView];

[actionSheet showInView:self];
```

[image]

Comment: Your image is correctly not underestand plese post complete screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code

```
actionSheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
actionSheet.frame = CGRectMake(0, 234, 320, 256);

UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,40)];

[pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonTapped:)];
[barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonTapped:)];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];

[pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
[actionSheet addSubview:pickerToolbar];


//-----------
maritalStatusPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 216)];
maritalStatusPickerView.delegate = self;
maritalStatusPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
//        [self addSubview:maritalStatusPickerView];

[actionSheet addSubview:maritalStatusPickerView];

[self.view addSubview:actionSheet];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are adding maritalStatusPickerView 2 times

```
[self addSubview:maritalStatusPickerView];

[actionSheet addSubview:maritalStatusPickerView];
```

Comment: that was added by mistake but even after removing that it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Just include the frame of actionsheet to your code after initialization

```
actionSheet.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 256);
```

refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051512/add-uiview-as-subview-on-uiactionsheet)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add your action sheet in your view, and change the co-Ordinate if you want to open pickerview from bottom of view.

```
[actionSheet addSubview:maritalStatusPickerView];

//Replace this :  [actionSheet showInView:self];

[self.view addSubview:actionSheet];
```