# Adding UIPickerView to UIActionSheet (buttons at the bottom)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

I want to

1. show a picker view (sliding up)
2. deactivate the background while it's visible
3. show (UIActionSheet) buttons at the bottom (not at the top)

It seems to me an easy solution at first since you can find code for adding a picker view to an action sheet everywhere in the web but all solutions position the buttons at top and **I need to put the buttons at the bottom of the action sheet (alignment?)**.

Is this possible? I guess it is if I look at: [Example](http://s3.amazonaws.com/files.posterous.com/app-incubator/mplGAlcfmHlCwDnjcpqtrfyIqsjvafGjvdnJcBvrGnzJgkkElpFHoooroojE/media_httpdldropboxco_mAbpk.png.scaled500.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFZAE65UYRT34AOQ&Expires=1366476962&Signature=Ub/dgv/2gghKSP%2b8SA1gpJcYN1s=)

Regards

Jeven

**EDITED (my solution based on coded dads solution)**

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;

    UISegmentedControl *backButton =  [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Back", nil]] ;
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    backButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.10 green:0.20 blue:0.52 alpha:0.5];
    backButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnActionCancelClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 220.0, 280.0, 40.0);

    UISegmentedControl *acceptButton =  [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Accept", nil]] ;
    [acceptButton addTarget:self action:@selector(anotherFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    acceptButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.10 green:0.20 blue:0.52 alpha:0.5];
    acceptButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    acceptButton.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 280.0, 280.0, 40.0);

    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
    [actionSheet addSubview:backButton];
    [actionSheet addSubview:acceptButton];

    [actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
    [actionSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0,150,320, 400)];
```

... then just apply iPhone 5/iphone 4 dependent view size constraints

**EDITED 2:**
Just another hint! Originally I wanted to use the standard Actionsheet, but didn't want to place the pickerview at the bottom. I didn't find a way how to move the buttons. Obviously it s really simple: [Add UIView as subView on UIActionSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051512/add-uiview-as-subview-on-uiactionsheet) Good to know ;)

Comment: You can simply ditch UIActionSheet and do a UIView with a UIPickerView and a couple of UIButtons

Comment: `UIActionSheet` is not meant to have arbitrary subviews added to it. It's sole purpose is to show a set of buttons. That's it. Use a more appropriate solution. Using such things incorrectly are destined to break terribly some day when Apple completely changes the layout or look of the action sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 possibilites:

**Option1: the big tweak.**

ActionSheet shows the buttons with the order defined during init. So place some dummy buttons at the top and Cancel will be the only visible, all other buttons will be hidden by the pickerview. Code *(warning-tweak at otherButtonTitles)*:

```
UIActionSheet *menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Actionsheet"
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];

UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.dataSource = self;

[menu addSubview:pickerView];
[menu showInView:self.view];
[menu setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 500)];

CGRect pickerRect = pickerView.bounds;
pickerRect.origin.y = 35;
pickerView.frame = pickerRect;
```

**Option2: the selfmade**

```
menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Actionsheet"
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.dataSource = self;
CGRect pickerRect = pickerView.bounds;
pickerRect.origin.y = 35;
pickerView.frame = pickerRect;

UIButton *startbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
startbtn.frame = CGRectMake(80,230, 170, 73);
[startbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[startbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedbuttonCancel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[menu addSubview:pickerView];
[menu addSubview:startbtn];
[menu showInView:self.view];
[menu setFrame:CGRectMake(0,150,320, 350)];
```

Check that for option2 the button should be on the actionsheet unless the clicks will not be dispatched to the selector method.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, unfortunately in the second example the pickerview is not shown (just a black square). Why is that? Ah ok, because "pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;" is missing ;)