# Place Cancel button in UIActionSheet at the bottom

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

In UIActionSheet i have a uitableview and cancel button. By default cancel button appears at the top. I want to make it appear at the bottom after tableview. How do i do that?

Answer (score 6):

it is work for me:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"SomeTitle" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Some Action"];        
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = actionSheet.numberOfButtons -1;
```

Comment: You are right on. If you use `addButtonWithTitle:` rather than taking care of all of it with the initializer then you'll need to specify the index of the cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and Cancel button is at the bottom:

```
menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Actionsheet"
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:@"destructive"
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"other1", nil];
menu.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
[menu addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
```

By default Cancel [button is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760545/action-sheet-doesnt-show-cancel-button-on-ipad), adding a Cancel will shows it.

**BUT:** if you have additional gui elements on your actionsheet you have to

**option1)** position those to hide other buttons (to have space for your gui element). Its a tweak, but can work in some situation  OR

**option2)** you have to manually add your button to the actionsheet

Actionsheet's built-in buttons are not align-able to the bottom freely because the purpose is different for this built-in gui elements.

See this: [Adding UIPickerView to UIActionSheet (buttons at the bottom)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122487/adding-uipickerview-to-uiactionsheet-buttons-at-the-bottom/16140387#16140387)

Comment: this works because u have couple of other buttons above cancel button. But in my case i dont have any other button. its just a tableview and cancel button

Comment: Finally I understand your set-up, so I think only option for you is to add a UIButton to your ActionSheet.

Comment: What u might to make sure (for me it was a problem) to place your uibutton on the uiactionsheet canvas (frame). Without this uibutton presses will not dispatch properly. This can arise if uiactionsheet's frame is not as big as all elements can be placed correctly on it.

Comment: For custom adding UIBUtton see my SO link in this post... and if it is works for you you may accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Example in **Swift**:

```
func presentMyActionSheetIOS7() {
    let actionSheet: UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "What do you want to do?", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: nil, destructiveButtonTitle: nil)

    actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Change Transparency")
    actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Hide Photo")
    actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
    actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = actionSheet.numberOfButtons - 1

    actionSheet.showInView(self.view)
}

func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    switch buttonIndex {
        case 0:
            println("Change Transparency")
        case 1:
            println("Hide Photo")
        case 2:
            println("Cancel")
        default:
            println("Default")
    }
}
```